# No route for post comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ive been having a problem now for 2 days, i followed many videos and tutorials on how to add comments to a post, and for everyone else it seemed to work smoothly.

I got 4 controllers, Users,Posts,Comments and Walls , basically this site is gonna be a facebook clone. So im displaying everything on the Wall index.html.erb

The error im getting is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:post_id]
```

Routes:

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
      resources :uploads
      resources :users
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments 
      end
      resources :walls
      root 'walls#index'
    end
```

Comments-controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:content))
    @comment.post_id = @post.id
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    # @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit[:content])
    # @comment.post_id = @post.id
    respond_to do |format|
     if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      #  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    # def comment_params
    #    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    # end

    def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end
end
```

Posts-controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      #  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.save
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:image,:content,:youtube_url))
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@post) }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@post) }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:content, :image, :username, :avatar, :youtube_url,:image_cache)
    end
end
```

I am rendering the form in the index.html.erb for the wall controller index

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

And the form loop
views/walls/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="comments">
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
      byebug
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'comments js-auto-size', id: 'alex2' ,:rows => 1  %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I dont understand why it cant find the post_id though :/

Comment: you must send post_id param in url

Comment: How would i write that Gladis?
:url  post_id  ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `comments` is nested inside `posts` in routes, you have to pass `post_id` to the `index` in `CommentsController`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post

  def index
    @comments = @post.comments
  end
end

# in view
<%= link_to "Comments", post_comments_path(@post) %>
```

Otherwise, you can define `comments` to be independent resources so you can do it without passing `post_id`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :comments 
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried that,

The error i have been stuck on forever is the form loop


<div class="comments">
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'comments js-auto-size', id: 'alex2' ,:rows => 1  %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

undefined method `post_comments_path'

Comment: I think the problem is, that i wanna render the new comment form and the comment in the wall/index.html.erb , showing the posts for my wallscontroller is no problem.

Showing the Comments doesnt seem to work though, if i got nested resources

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:post_id]